# How to find exact string matches between two columns, and if a match copy a string from a different dataframe into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes I am comparing, I am looking at the columns from the two and seeing if the two have an exact string match between them. If they do I have string I want to copy into a new column on the first dataframe. When I do merge it is making my first dataframe longer because it is copying rows.
I believe I need a function to scan through each row and look if there is a string match and make a new row on my df_1

```
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'ShipName': ['D', 'A', 'C']})
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'ShipName': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',], 'ShipKey' = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']}
```

end result to look like this because I compared the two dataframes and I found the ShipName that matched and looked at the corresponding key to see what value I should copy into my df_1

```
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'ShipName': ['D', 'A', 'C'], 'ShipKey_Matched': ['Fourth', 'First', 'Third']})
```

Comment: `df_1.merge(df_2)`?

Comment: when I merge df_2 to df_1 it increases the rows by over 10,000 even with a left merge

Comment: Cannot reproduce with your example. I get three rows as expected. Your original data probably has duplicated ShipName